# Power BI Right function not allowing for calculated length

Tags: powerbi

I'm having an issue with cleaning seriously messy data. However I can save about 90% of it if i can just remove the first 11 characters of a string. Please can someone help explain why this isn't working?

[image]

Comment: dont use Table[Column] = Blank(); better use ISBLANK(Table[Column]); 
Why you want take Right from BLANK?

Comment: Does it work with `length2`? Negative values might be causing the error.